# Gnu parallel rsync hanging indefinitely

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync, gnu-parallel

To be clear, I am running this exact command(variables changed) in a `gnu parallel` setting:

```
/usr/bin/parallel -q -j20 
    rsync --recursive -av -e ssh -oCompression=no -x -T 
    -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oConnectTimeout=15 
    -i ssh_key -l some_username --chmod=Dugo+rwx,Fugo+rw 
    --files-from {} /some/base/dir somehostame:/some/other/dir
```

This consumes about 50 files(containing list of file/directory names for rsync), across 20 workers through `gnu parallel`. I ran the above yesterday night, and I came back to work to see that there is still 1 rsync job, hanging:

```
rsync --recursive -av -e ssh -oCompression=no -x -T -
    oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oConnectTimeout=15 
    -i ssh-beta-secdata-20180515t213639 -l diskmaker 
    --chmod=Dugo+rwx,Fugo+rw 
    --files-from ./some_filelist /some/base/dir somehostname:/some/other/dir
```

So to be clear, `some_filelist` is a list of directories I want to do rsync in.

I'll take the files from the base(as if `chroot`'d) from `/some/base/dir` to a remote directory `somehostname:/some/other/dir`.

So there are like, 500 jobs that `parallel` pulls from. I analyzed each file list, and there's nothing special about this `./some_filelist`; standard 200 files from an rsync dryrun.

Does anyone have diagnosis for this problem? I am completely lost to how this could happen. I can post more snippets if required.

Comment: can you list what files the hanging process has open (`lsof -p pid`), and what syscall it is hanging on (`strace -p pid`).

Comment: Does it work, if you run the hanging command on the command line? Can you try splitting `./some_filelist` and see if some parts work find? Is the the same part that is hanging if you use `parallel --shuf`?

Comment: Hope you make sure different `rsync` processes do not read/write to the same dirs.

Comment: It looks as if `rsync` would have _some issues_ sorting out what options are meant for `ssh` and what options are not meant for `ssh` (since the option-argument to `rsync -e` is not a single string).

Answer (score 0):

As Ole Tange suggested, you may see that rsync asks you for the ssh password, when you try rsyncing with only one argument(a directory name in your case). When I encountered the same problem in my experiments, I figured out that parallel doesn't prompt you for the ssh password, but in the background it needs one.

Applying one of the answers on [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/555799/how-to-setup-rsync-without-password-with-ssh-on-unix-linux) solved my problem. It says in particular;

1) Create a public key;

> ssh-keygen

2) Copy that key to "somehostname"

> ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@somehostname OR somehostname's IP address

That's all. After these steps, ssh connections between those two machines doesn't require a ssh password to be provided. In my case, the command stopped hanging using this configuration.